# R + Shiny : Save Uploaded Dataset to List/ choose from list item to view

Tags: r, list, shiny, dataset

i've looked all over the internet and tried multiple solution but none of them seems to be working. 
In short this is my problem: I created a shiny app where the user can upload csv files and save them in a dataset. Now i want to save each uploaded dataset in a list which would help me via a selectInput button to choose which dataset to view this is the code i wrote so far :

```
server <- function(input, output) {


  datasetlist <- list()



  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    input$update

    tryCatch({
      df <- read.csv(
        input$file1$datapath,
        header = isolate(input$header),
        sep = isolate(input$sep),
        dec = isolate(input$dec),
        quote = isolate(input$quote)
      )

    },
    error = function(e) {
      # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
      stop(safeError(e))
    })


    # when reading semicolon separated files,
    # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error


    if (isolate(input$disp == "head")) {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })

  output$manage <- renderUI({

    selectInput("dataset", "Dataset", choices = datasetlist[], selected = datasetlist[1]) 
  })
}
```

Bonus point : i would be glad if someone were also to point how to deleter records from the list without affection the whole list

**EDIT 1:** following the answer i received earlier here's the complete code now, the problem is that i can't seem to find a way to display the tables of the datasets

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyFiles)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30 * 1024 ^ 2)

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(#theme= shinytheme("paper"),

  # Application title
  navbarPage(
    "Title",
    # Sidebar with input

    tabPanel("Data Manager",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 uiOutput("manage"),
                 fileInput(
                   "file1",
                   "Choose CSV File",
                   multiple = FALSE,
                   accept = c("text/csv",
                              "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                              ".csv")
                 ),
                 # Horizontal line ----
                 tags$hr(),

                 fluidRow(
                   # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
                   column(4 ,checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)),

                   # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
                   column(8, radioButtons(
                     "disp",
                     "Display",
                     choices = c(Head = "head",
                                 All = "all"),
                     selected = "head",
                     inline = TRUE
                   ))),

                 fluidRow(# Input: Select separator ----
                          column(
                            4, selectInput(
                              "sep",
                              "Separator",
                              choices = c(
                                Comma = ",",
                                Semicolon = ";",
                                Tab = "\t"
                              ),
                              selected = ";"
                            )
                          ),


                          # Input: Select decimals ----
                          column(
                            4 , selectInput(
                              "dec",
                              "Decimal",
                              choices = c("Comma" = ",",
                                          "Period" = '.'),
                              selected = ','
                            )
                          )),

                 # Input: Select quotes ----
                 fluidRow(column(8 , selectInput(
                   "quote",
                   "Quote",
                   choices = c(
                     None = "",
                     "Double Quote" = '"',
                     "Single Quote" = "'"
                   ),
                   selected = '"'
                 ))),

                 # Horizontal line ----
                 tags$hr(),


                 actionButton("update", "Update")




               ),
               mainPanel(fluidRow(tableOutput("contents")))
             ))
  ))

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(
    datasetlist = list()
  )

  observe({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.
    req(input$file1)

    input$update

    tryCatch({
      df <- read.csv(
        input$file1$datapath,
        header = isolate(input$header),
        sep = isolate(input$sep),
        dec = isolate(input$dec),
        quote = isolate(input$quote)
      )

    },
    error = function(e) {
      # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
      stop(safeError(e))
    })
    # when reading semicolon separated files,
    # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
    isolate(
      rv$datasetlist <- c(rv$datasetlist,list(df))
    )
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "selected_dataset",
      choices = 1:length(rv$datasetlist),
      selected = input$selected_dataset
    )
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(length(rv$datasetlist) >= input$selected_dataset)


    df <- rv$datasetlist[[input$selected_dataset]]
    if (isolate(input$disp == "head")) {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })

  output$manage <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      selectInput("selected_dataset", "Dataset", choices = '', selected = 1) 

    )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the uploaded files by user to a folder say Selected_Files using `file.copy()`, then use `eventReactive()` to read all the files in the folder to a list say datasetlist. Name the elements of the datasetlist to the file names. You can use this list reactive context in renderUI/renderTable using `datasetlist()`.

I have written the code below which might solve your purpose.Further note `read.csv` has `sep` argument which takes care of different separators. I used radioButtons for user to provide file separators.

**Edit:** To capture the file format of all the uploaded files correctly I created a list `df` capturing the user input file formats and saving it as an R Object *File_Format.rds* in the working directory. Then use `readRDS` to load the saved list as `old_df` and append it to current `df`.

**Edit2:** I figured that when same file is uploaded with different parameters the name of the list `File_Format` remains identical hence the first element of the duplicate gets selected. I fixed this issue by prefixing the count of upload as an index to the names. Further, at the beginning of the code I added two statements to delete the RDS file and all the files in the folder `Selected_Files`. Hence whenever the application is opened these files are deleted first and then the interactive session follows.

Updated code is below

```
library(shiny)
if (file.exists("File_Format.rds")) file.remove("File_Format.rds")
do.call(file.remove, list(list.files("Selected_Files", full.names = TRUE)))

ui <- fluidPage(

  # tableOutput("contents"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
              multiple = FALSE,
              accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),
    # Horizontal line ----
    tags$hr(),

    # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
    checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

    # Input: Select separator ----
    radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                 choices = c(Comma = ",",
                             Semicolon = ";",
                             Tab = "\t"),
                 selected = ","),

    # Input: Select quotes ----
    radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                 choices = c(None = "",
                             "Double Quote" = '"',
                             "Single Quote" = "'"),
                 selected = '"'),

    # Horizontal line ----
    tags$hr(),

    # Upload Button
    actionButton("uploadId", "Upload")
  ),

  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(

    # # Output: Data file ----

    uiOutput("manage"),

    # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
    uiOutput("select"),

    # Display Button
    actionButton("displayid", "Display"),


    tableOutput("contents")


  )
)


########### Server ###########

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  # Copy uploaded files to local folder
  observeEvent(input$uploadId,{
    if (is.null(input$file1) ) {    return(NULL)  }  
    file.copy(from = input$file1$datapath, to =  paste0('Selected_Files/',input$file1$name )  )
    df <- list(file = input$file1$name , header= input$header,
               sep = input$sep,dec = input$dec,
               quote = input$quote,
               index = input$uploadId)
    if(input$uploadId > 1){
      old_df <- readRDS("File_Format.rds")
      df <- sapply(names(old_df),function(n){c(old_df[[n]],df[[n]])},simplify=FALSE)
    }
    saveRDS(df, "File_Format.rds")

  })

  # Load all the uplaoded files to a list
  datasetlist <- eventReactive(input$uploadId,{
    # Selected_Files <- list.files("Selected_Files/")
    File_Format <- readRDS("File_Format.rds")
    datalist <- list()
    datalist <- lapply(1:length(File_Format[[1]]), function(d) read.csv(paste0("Selected_Files/",File_Format$file[d] ),
                                                            header = File_Format$header[d],
                                                            sep = File_Format$sep[d],
                                                            dec = File_Format$dec[d],
                                                            quote = File_Format$quote[d]))
    names(datalist) <- paste(File_Format$index, File_Format$file,sep = ". ")
    return(datalist)
  })

  output$manage <- renderUI({
    data <- datasetlist()
    selectInput("dataset", "Dataset", choices = names(data), selected = names(data))
  })

  output$select <- renderUI({
    data <- datasetlist()
    radioButtons("disp", "Display", choices = c(Head = "head",All = "all"),
                 selected = "head")
  })

  # Display Selected File
  observeEvent(input$displayid, {
    output$contents <- renderTable({

      data <- datasetlist()
      sub_df <- data[[paste0(input$dataset)]]
      if (isolate(input$disp == "head")) {
        return(head(sub_df))
      }
      else {
        return(sub_df)
      }
    })
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Great Answer!! and a great method!! worked like a charm thank you!!

Comment: Thanks, but I have noticed an issue in the code. If you are loading files of different separators, all of the files in the local folder are read in the format last uploaded. Need to fix this!!

Comment: any suggestions on how to fix this ? i'll be trying too and in case i found out how i'll post here too

Comment: I am trying a work around too,  will post it when I hit it!

Comment: I have found a solution!. I have updated the code above (edited it). Check if it works

Comment: I tried the edit code it works but now i found an issue with it: whenever you upload a file but then then reupload the same one with different parameters ( header ) the display doesn't update and jist stays woth the old parameters + the rds doesn't auto delete after finishing the execution

Comment: I have fixed the issues and updated the code (edit2). Check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it. I haven't tested it since you only supplied half of your code and I am to lazy at the moment to build my own ui file.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(
    datasetlist = list()
  ) 

  observe({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.
    req(input$file1)

    input$update

    tryCatch({
      df <- read.csv(
        input$file1$datapath,
        header = isolate(input$header),
        sep = isolate(input$sep),
        dec = isolate(input$dec),
        quote = isolate(input$quote)
      )

    },
    error = function(e) {
      # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
      stop(safeError(e))
    })
    # when reading semicolon separated files,
    # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
    isolate(
      rv$datasetlist = c(rv$datasetlist,list(df))
    )
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "selected_dataset",
      choices = 1:length(rv$datasetlist),
      selected = input$selected_dataset
    )
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(length(rv$datasetlist) >= input$selected_dataset)


    df <- rv$datasetlist[[input$selected_dataset]]
    if (isolate(input$disp == "head")) {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })

  output$manage <- renderUI({
    tagList(
    selectInput("selected_dataset", "Dataset", choices = 1, selected = 1) 

    )
  })
}
```

you might have to add some `as.numeric()` around the `input$selected_dataset` since selectInput normally returns a string and not a numeric.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank You for replying @Bertin Baron, i tested your solution unfortunately it gave me this error :Error in reactiveValues(datasetlist <- list()) : 
  All arguments passed to reactiveValues() must be named.

Comment: sorry the `<-` should be a simple `=`

Comment: it works so far thank you, should only figure out how to display the table when choosing the dataset from select button because so far i have no output

Comment: I give up, could you please tell how to display the output$contents i have tried every possible way and it doesn't seem to be working, 
EDIT : I changed my code above so that now it contains the whole code as it is now